# Java - access method from restricted package

Tags: java

I am facing an issue with creating  an object of a class and access method from a restricted package. I cannot use reflection.  To explain it in detail, say we have 2 packages A and B.
A can not access classes from B
But B can access classes from A.
But for some requirement I have to run a method Of a class located in B from A.
Is there any method to do so?!

Comment: likely, there is a reason why the access is restricted.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to change the scope of your class (and probably methods) in B package from `package-protected` to `public` or, as you have already said, use a reflection (which is not a good practice at all).

And there's nothing else you could do. Make your choice.